# File in Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have a problem to get json. 
If I use:
`$.getJSON("file:///E:/WebProject/json/"+name+".json",resolve)`
It works!

But if I use:
`$.getJSON("/json/"+name+".json",resolve)`
It does not work. Why?

Comment: You don't have a running web server, right?

Comment: @Vohuman He's using Firefox, not Chrome, so that's fine, local Ajax requests are allowed.

Comment: Look at the *actual* request sent to the server. Does the resource path correctly match what is expected/hosted? What is the response?

Comment: @blex How do you know OP is using Firefox? The point wasn't Same-origin  Policy.

Comment: @Vohuman Ok. Well, as you figured, Chrome and IE would block these requests, but not FF. And since his first call is working, I figured he was probably using FF, and that not having a server was not the issue. It's just the wrong path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Changing

```
 $.getJSON("/json/"+name+".json",resolve)
```

to

```
 $.getJSON("json/"+name+".json",resolve)
```

/json looks for the file in the root but I think json folder is in your web folder, not in the root.

Comment: @JossefHarush take a look at it now.

Answer (score 0):

## It's because ...

When the first character is `/`, the browser fetch the file from the root of the *site address*

**e.g.**

`file:///E:/WebProject` <kbd>+</kbd> `/json/name.json` <kbd>=</kbd> **`file:///E:/json/name.json`** (maybe even without the `E` letter)

**otherwise**, the addition is relative:

`file:///E:/WebProject` <kbd>+</kbd> `json/name.json` <kbd>=</kbd> **`file:///E:/WebProject/json/name.json`**

---

- as @Alp suggested, omit the first `/` and you should be fine
- consider using a small local development server - if using python, cd to that folder and type `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`